# how can I make a larger array with cubic interpolation and acces all the calculated values?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, cubic

I am trying to get a cubic interpolation of a data set, e.g y = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400] and x = [0, 28, 54, 78, 100]. With the linear interpolation from the numpy library everything just works fine but I need a smooth data set. In the code sample below the result is a data set that looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccx9j.png)

Instead I want a data set that looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEktR.png)
It is important for me that the interpolation gives me an array which gives me access to the DistanceLong value for every 2 seconds, which is the factor. With the scipy functions I did not got it to work. I hope you guys can give me some help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def interplan(Timestamp, Distance, factor):
    Time = np.zeros(len(Timestamp)-1)
    NewDistance= np.zeros(len(Timestamp)-1)
    TotalTime = 0
    TotalDistance = 0

    for i in range(len(Timestamp)-1):
        TotalTime += Timestamp[i]
        Time[i] = TotalTime
        TotalDistance += Distance[i]
        NewDistance[i] = TotalDistance


    Time =  np.hstack((0,Time))
    NewDistance =  np.hstack((0,NewDistance))

    k = np.array(range((int(TotalTime+1))))
    t = k*factor
    DistanceLong = np.interp(t,Time,NewDistance)

    return DistanceLong


Timestamp = np.array([28, 26, 24, 22,0])
Distance = np.array([100, 100, 100, 100,0])
factor = 2

DistanceLong = interplan(Timestamp, Distance, factor)
BiggestVal = max(DistanceLong)
IndexLastVal = np.where(DistanceLong == BiggestVal)
DistanceLong = DistanceLong[0:IndexLastVal[0][1]]

Speed = np.zeros(len(DistanceLong))
for i in range(len(DistanceLong)-1):
    Speed[i] = ((DistanceLong[i+1]-DistanceLong[i])/2)*3.6

PerfectSpeed = (Distance/Timestamp)*3.6

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(Speed,linewidth=0.8)


plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(PerfectSpeed,linewidth=0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

For cubic interpolation you can use either `splrep/ splev`, or, in newer scipy, `CubicSpline`, or, in still newer scipy, `make_interp_spline`.

Comment: I can not access the values when using CubicSpline. When I print it I get: <scipy.interpolate._cubic.CubicSpline object at 0x0000024048117A98>

Comment: CubicSpline constructs s callable object which evaluates the interpolant on its argument.